# Why is one of the high side MOSFETs heating up in the inverter design using egs002?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, mosfet-driver

I am totally new to electronics and so I don't have the tools and knowledge enough to troubleshoot this problem. I am attaching a picture of the schematic.

[image: Image for the inverter circuit and connector to egs002]

When I power up the circuit using a bench power supply set to 15v and current limited to 4A for the egs module powers up nicely and blinks 4 times indicating undervoltage. This pulls <1w from the supply.
When I hook up a torroidal transformer 170VA I have laying around the module pulls about 15w. Only one of the high side MOSFETs though connected to 2HO is heating up compared to the rest.
Any light to what is wrong is highly appreciated.

And here is the image of the schematic for 12v buck supply

[image]

I measured this and it deliver only 11.2v when supplied with 15v source and 10.8v when supplied with 12v source. I also observed when MOSFETs gate is supplied with 10.8v it's causing a drop of approximately 2v.